# Doctrine - mapping to a non entity class

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Is there a possibility to map doctrine's native query to a class that is not annotated as ORM entity?
I have a basic class under `App\Model`

```
class BasicModel
{
    private int $weight;
    private int $points;
}
```

And my goal is to map the result of a query directly into this non entity class.

```
$rsm = new ResultSetMapping();
$rsm->addEntityResult(BasicModel::class, 'b');
$rsm->addFieldResult('b', 'points', 'points');
$rsm->addFieldResult('b', 'weight', 'weight');
$query = $this->em->createNativeQuery('select points, weight from some_table', $rsm);
$result = $query->getResult();
```

Currently, an error occurs

> The class 'App\Model\BasicModel' was not found in the chain configured namespaces App\Entity

I don't want to annotate this class as Entity, since I don't need this information to be stored in database.

My current stack:

- Symfony 5
- MySQL 8
- Doctrine 2

Comment: Sadly no.  Be nice if it did.  You would think that the addFieldResult method would provide all the mapping info needed but that is not how the implementation works.  Result set mappings are actually what Doctrine uses internally for it's DQL queries and it's heavily tied to the entity manager and unit of work stuff.  You can drop down to the DBAL connection and do you own mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that is not possible. Doctrine is build as a Database Abstraction Layer (DBAL) and does not allow for this use case.

I see two paths forward. I know you say you do not want that, but since you have MySQL in your stack, you could opt to add the data anyway to the database and have the entity as a proper entity class. The other option is to not use Doctrine and build a different implementation to list all entities.